# Excel chart show year intervals on axis

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

ON the x-axis of a chart in Excel I would like to show the separates when years change and put the year in the middle of the interval.

How can I do that?

See the below image for an example of what I want to achieve.

http://imageshack.us/a/img268/7619/chartes.png

Comment: If I could add a few month as well would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your data is laid out, but you can do this by putting the year in its own column.

[image]

Then select the month and year as the axis labels.

[image]

Source: [Show Months & Years in Charts without Cluttering](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/17/show-months-years-in-charts/)

Answer (score 3):

Format years as dates in source. For horizontal axis use Years for Major unit and Months for Minor unit. Format Axis Number as something like "   |   "yyyy may be about as close as Excel will get you, without say overlaying a text box with the desired layout:

[image: SU487955 example]

Comment: This does not work in Excel 2007. I am installing Office 2010 now!

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me, because I didn't want to show the months/weeks/days.

Therefore I added a layer only containing "|" and got rid of the tick marks from Excel by selecting the "None" option for both the tick mark types in the "Axis Options" of the Format Axis menu, and the "No line in the Line Color option. You can improve the example by setting the "the label distance to axis" to 1 under the "Axis Options".

Cheers

Comment: The answers move around.  Which one was "above" when you wrote this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can now right-click on the axis, then go to Format Axis, Axis Options, scroll down to the bottom and enter the format code `yyyy`:

[image: Screenshot]